# How are new Stack Overflow ques always at the top of a google search

Tags: discussion, seo

I noticed an interesting thing today. I had posted a ques on the main stack Overflow website . This post  garnered 14 views and 0 votes. Definetely not  a popular PGE.
Yet as I searched related keywords to my ques on google the stack overflow website with my ques was ranked first amoung the rest.
How is Stack.Overflow doing this ?